# Select that generate a different nput type number

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html markup.

```
<select name="components">
  <option value="solo">solo</option>
  <option value="group">group</option>
  <option value="band">band</option>
</select>
```

I want to generate a input type number after select an option without reload the page.

Like this:

```
 // When I select solo option:
<input type="number" name="dancers" value="1" min="1" max="1">

 // When I select group option:
<input type="number" name="dancers" value="2" min="2" max="6">

 // When I select band option:
<input type="number" name="dancers" value="7" min="7" max="12">
```

*I need to submit only the input generated by the option selected.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store data in object structure, and when options selected set value, min, max to attribute according to selected option:

Javascript:

```
data = {"solo": {"value": 1, "min": 1, "max": 1},
        "group": {"value": 2, "min": 2, "max": 6},
        "band": {"value": 7, "min": 7, "max": 12}};

 $("select[name='components']").change(function(){
    selected_option = $(this).val();
    selected_data = data[selected_option];
    ["value", "min", "max"].forEach(function(key){
      $("input[name='dancers']").attr(key, selected_data[key]);
    });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<select name="components">
  <option value="solo">solo</option>
  <option value="group">group</option>
  <option value="band">band</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="dancers">
```

[jsfilddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7aatx91/#&togetherjs=VCaD2vP4Fa)

Comment: can you help me with the full code (html markup and jquery), please? I am not too good with the jQuery and the object structures :(

Comment: thank you. I don't know why but the value of the input number is not filled with the selected option number.

Comment: check jsfiddle link added

Comment: Works great now. Thank you so much!